# Installing rbenv, permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, vps

I am setting up my VPS to deploy my rails app, but permission denied error keeps happening on my server side. I had to reinstall perl and curl, and now I'm getting the following:

```
deployer@max:~$ rbenv bootstrap-ubuntu-12-04
bash: /usr/bin/python: permission denied
```

I tried reinstalling python but came up with no success. How should I solve it?

**Update:**

```
root@max:/home/deployer# cd /usr
root@max:/usr# cd bin
root@max:/usr/bin# cd python
bash: cd: python: not a directory
```

Does this mean python is not installed correctly?

**Update:**

```
deployer@max:~$ ls -l 'which python'
total 0
deployer@max:~$ python
bash: /usr/bin/python: permission denied
```

I thought this meant python was not installed correctly, so I computed the following

```
deployer@d:~$ su root
root@d:/home/deployer# apt-get install python
python package is already the latest version
```

So I failed to find the solution yet.

Comment: What does `ls -l \`which python\`` output? Can you run `python`, what happens?

Comment: `which python` has to be backticked not quoted, copy as is from my comment.

Comment: @soulseekah, it gives "Total 0"

Comment: What does simply `which python` output? Also try `chmod 755 /usr/bin/python` maybe. What do the `which` commands output when running root, especially the one with `ls`?

Comment: which commands and chmod 755 do not output anything when I'm on deployer user, but when I'm running root, `which python` outputs Python 2.7.3

Comment: Then `sudo chmod 0755 /usr/bin/python` and see if that helps. Seems like the execution bit is off for `deployer`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20470/discussion-between-maximus-s-and-soulseekah)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out it was a permissions issue, here are some general tips on how to debug a `permission denied` error when trying to execute a binary, `python` in this case:

`` ls -l `which python` `` - tries to retrieve full path and permissions, like `-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody nobody 9644 2012-12-02 13:15 /tmp/env/bin/python`

Has to be run as a privileged user if permissions are `0000`, for example.

`sudo chmod 0755 /usr/bin/python` usually helps.